# How to make an optionally invoked function?

Tags: javascript

I have module called styles.

```
export default (props = {}) => ({

  tile: {
    width: props.width,
    listStyle: "none"
  },
 banner: {
  color: 'red',
 }
})
```

If I `import styles from './styles.js;` I basically want to be able to two things:

get tile styles like this: `styles({width:}).tile`

and get the banner styles like this: `styles.banner`, so without calling it like `styles().banner`.

How to do this?

EDIT: I'm so sorry, failed to make my question clear. The object *defined* should always have the structure as:

```
tile: {
    width: props.width,
    listStyle: "none"
  },
 banner: {
  color: 'red',
 }
```

The function that returns this object can look whatever you want to.

Comment: `styles().banner`

Comment: @JLRishe sorry, updated my question. I need the function to be optionally invoked. So styles.banner instead of styles().banner.

Comment: @J.Reku Then it's not a function any more. How would you pass arguments?

Comment: You might be looking for `Object.assign(styles, styles())`

Comment: @JLRishe i know it's pointless, but I really want to figure out how to do it. I was looking for a way to do it based on arguments object and optionally returning an IIFE, then i got lost.

Comment: @J.Reku Without a call, there is no `arguments` object and no returning.

Comment: @J.Reku No. `styles` is a single value - regardless whether it is produced by an IIFE or not. It doesn't know whether it will be called beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you would want to do this, but you can do the following. There's a need to distinguish which styles can be returned without parameters ("independentStyles"), and those that require input values:

```js
const independentStyles = {
  banner: {
    color: 'red',
  },
};

const styles = (props = {}) => Object.assign({}, independentStyles, {
  tile: {
    width: props.width,
    listStyle: "none"
  },
});

// put the properties on the function object
Object.assign(styles, independentStyles);

console.log(styles({ width: 30 }).tile);   // { width: 30, listStyle: 'none' }
console.log(styles().tile);                // { width: undefined, listStyle: 'none' }
console.log(styles().banner);              // { color: 'red' }
console.log(styles.banner);                // { color: 'red' }
console.log(styles.tile);                  // undefined - can't be determined without props


// export default styles;
```

Answer (score 0):

A function is an object, so you can also attach other properties to a function. See the below code snippet (in your real code you would have the export default)

```js
const styles = (props = {}) => ({
  tile: {
    width: props.width,
    listStyle: "none"
  },
});

styles.banner = {
  color: 'red',
};

// export default styles

// Test code:
console.log(styles.banner);
console.log(styles({width: 10}).tile);
```